# 'today announced' vs. '*yesterday announced'

Tags: syntax

In my grammar, 'Uber today announced a new invention' sounds fine but 'Uber yesterday announced a new invention' is marked if not ungrammatical. Any literature on this/explanations?

Comment: Could you provide some more context, e.g. in which sentences you think the contrast is most striking? This will help us providing better answers to your question.

Comment: As a native speaker, those sound equally grammatical to me.

Comment: @Draconis Thanks. I'm also a native (Canadian) English speaker and I'm getting some markedness on the latter

Comment: I think both sentences would sound better if "today/yesterday" stood at the beginning or the end of the sentence.

Comment: @fdb, agreed but wanted to discuss this minimal pair (in my grammar)

Comment: Follow the second sentence with "but federal regulators today announced plans to to block their innovation". "SUBJ today V" is news-speak, and yesterday's new is not news, it's old news.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your getting a discourse effect from an unanalyzed and assumed context. Do you interpret 'Uber yesterday announced a new invention' as either of the following:

- *Breaking News! Uber yesterday announced a new invention.
- *This just happened! Uber yesterday announced a new invention.

These sentences work with 'today':

- Breaking News! Uber today announced a new invention.
- This just happened! Uber today announced a new invention. (perhaps redundant)